# Connection refused docker, laravel and mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

So I have this docker illustration

[image]

As you can see my laravel app is trying to do a database connection in the container where the MySQL server is being installed and setup.

The instance of laravel app is accessible using this port

`192.168.0.XX:3021`

and the container is accessible using this IP

`192.168.0.61`

and the MySQL Server credential is:

**USER3021** I just tried to create this user account with '%' wild card capability and with

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USER3021' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxxx';`

and when I try to connect the laravel app and MySQL server with this `.env` file

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=192.168.0.XX
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=myTable
 DB_USERNAME=USER3021
 DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

[image]

The laravel gives me an error like this

> Connection refused mysql

Comment: Change the port in `.env`

Comment: you my db port?

Comment: `DB_PORT=3021` instead of `DB_PORT=3306`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access Mysql through port `3021` but you defined port `3306`
Try changing them in .env file

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=192.168.0.XX
 DB_PORT=3021
 DB_DATABASE=myTable
 DB_USERNAME=USER3021
 DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.env` file and change port: ***`DB_PORT=3021`*** instead of ***`DB_PORT=3306`***

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=192.168.0.XX 
DB_PORT=3021 
DB_DATABASE=myTable     // Your Database Name 
DB_USERNAME=USER3021   // Yout Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx   // Your Database Password
```

After completion of *`.env`* edit please enter this command in your terminal to clear cache:

```sh
php artisan config:clear
```